# Change variable specific text with powershell and create a table

Tags: powershell, foreach, textchanged, formattable

I'm trying to change some words inside a variable that contains a table.

I was able to do it using a foreach with -replace but then I can't form again the table.

**1st try**

```
$vms = Get-AZVm -status | Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceGroupName , PowerState 
$tabla = foreach ($item in $vms) {
$item.Name
$item.ResourceGroupName
$item.PowerState -replace 'VM Deallocated','Apagada' -replace 'VM running','Encendida' 
} | Format-Table
```

**2nd try**

```
$vms |foreach{$_.PowerState -replace 'VM Deallocated','Apagada' -replace 'VM running','Encendida'} | Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceGroupName , PowerState | format-table -autosize
```

I expect after the replacement of text inside the table to leave the same as a table and not text

Comment: can you post the value in `$item.PowerState`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test this myself, but I think using a calculated property would be easiest:

```
$vms = Get-AzVM -status | 
       Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceGroupName, 
       @{Name = 'PowerState'; Expression = {($_.PowerState -replace 'VM Deallocated','Apagada') -replace 'VM running','Encendida'}} 

$vms | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: It perfectly worked! :) thanks a lot! below answer also worked thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would create my table inside an array and set its content...

```
$vms = Get-AZVm -status | Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceGroupName , PowerState 

$tabla = @{

    "Name" = ""
    "ResourceGroupName" = ""
    "PowerState" = ""

}

foreach ($item in $vms) {
    $record."Name" = $item.Name
    $record."ResourceGroupName" = $item.ResourceGroupName
    $record."PowerState" = $item.PowerState -replace 'VM Deallocated','Apagada' -replace 'VM running','Encendida' 
    $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -Property $record
    $tabla += $objRecord
}

$tabla
```

Comment: Thanks, it also worked, I can't mark both as correct, but they work, thanks!